# Trace sigma algebra and conditioning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Is there any connection between the trace sigma-algebra and probabilistic conditioning? Suppose we have a sub sigma-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ and a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Let $A$ be an event in $\mathcal{G}$ and $E$ an event in $\mathcal{F}$.

Do we have any relationship between $\mathbb{P}(E|\mathcal{G})$ and $\mathbb{P}(E|\mathcal{G}\cap A)$, where $\mathcal{G}\cap A$ denotes the trace sigma-algebra (i.e. all the intersections of the events in $\mathcal{G}$ with $A$)? Is there any connection between the concept of trace sigma algebra and the conditional measure $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|A)$ which I will denote $\mathbb{P}_A$?

I was thinking of relationships of the type $\mathbb{P}(E|\mathcal{G})(\omega)=\mathbb{P}(E|\mathcal{G}\cap A)(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in A$ or similar to $\mathbb{P}(E|\mathcal{G}\cap A)=\mathbb{P}_A(E|\mathcal{G})$. If not, what is the concept of trace sigma-algebra used for?

Comment: The tracę $\mathcal{G}_A:=\{A\cap G: G\in\mathcal{G}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $A$, For any set $F\in\mathcal{F}$
$$\mathbb{E}[F\cap A|\mathcal{G}_A]=\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{G}]|_A$$ where $\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{G}]|_A$ is the restriction of $\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{G}]$ to $A$. One can also use $\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{G}]$.

Comment: By restriction do you mean that for every $\omega\in A$, $\mathbb{E}[F|\mathcal{G}](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[F\cap A|\mathcal{G}\cap A](\omega)$? I am a bit confused by the notation here, since we can't take expectations of events. Did you mean $\mathbb{P}$ instead of $\mathbb{E}$ maybe?

Comment: Coorect. Notice that $\mathcal{G}\cap A$ is a $\sigma$-algenra open $A$, thus, it does not make sense to consider $\omega$'s outside $A$, $\mathbb{E}[F\cap A|\mathcal{G}\cap A]$ is a $\mathcal{G}\cap A$-measurable function on $A$.

Comment: In my post I assumed $A\in \mathcal{G}$, but from this interpretation as restriction, it does not seem to be necessary, we could as well take $A\in\mathcal{F}$ right?

Comment: Restriction is a most since the expectation is taken with respect to a probability measure on $A$. If $A\notin \mathcal{G}$, then $$\mathbb{E}[F\cap A|\mathcal{G}\cap A]=\mathbb{E}[F\cap A|\mathcal{G}]|_A$$